# Add program to mac osx and windows startup by code or installers?

Tags: java

I have a java system tray application that runs on both windows and mc osx.
I want to add my app to start up programs for both od those os-
which is best:

1. Check in code which os i'm on and then do a certain action accordingly?
2. Create a different installer for each os that will add the program to start up?

Also, is there any good example on the best Generic way adding program to windows(for all windows types??) by code or by install, and also a good example for creating a launch agent for the mac?

Thanks
Lior

#### Update

Initially i would go for #1, as it easier to manage other than managing installation packages for long. but on the other hand, it is not generic, and id like to keep my code generic as possible. And third, i'm on a very short schedule, if there is a 3rd party installers that can warp this up and create different os installer with start up, thats better, under the circumstance of course.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts of your own? What do **you** think is the best way, and why?

Comment: Initially i would go for #1, as it easier to manage other than managing installation packages for long. but on the other hand, it is not generic, and id like to keep my code generic as possible. And third, i'm on a very short schedule, if there is a 3rd party installers that can warp this up and create different os installer with start up, thats better, under the circumstance of course.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just a hint: that information belongs into the post itself.

Comment: Oh Sorry its my first post here :)

Comment: No worries :) That's why everyone curates and why first posts are peer reviewed. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing a multi platform Java application I advise you to follow it's 'Write once - run everywhere' rule and either create an self-executable jar file (both Mac and Windows are capable of running those, e.g. [explained here](http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=15486)) or you could try an out-of-the-box solution like [IzPack](http://izpack.org)

Comment: Thanks, does izpack supports start-up's or need to be written separately by scripts and so on?

Comment: It does, more over that you may also setup desktop shortcuts. Just check it's [excessive documentation](http://izpack.org/documentation/desktop-shortcuts.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

For #1: Check the system property `os.name` on a win 7 box you will get `Windows 7`. You can query system properties with

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

Comment: Thanks, BetaRide, but i have no issue with implementing #1, im just not sure whats better.